# DropDown Menu is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with my dropdown menu. Language and Request dropdowns are not working, only the Categories dropdown is working. There is something wrong with the javascript, here is the code

Html

```
<div id="mbmcpebul_wrapper" style="text-align:center;padding-left:215px;">
  <ul id="mbmcpebul_table" class="mbmcpebul_menulist css_menu">
  <li><div class="buttonbg gradient_button"><a href="Home" target="_self">Home</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="buttonbg gradient_button"><a href="Categories" target="_self">Categories</a></div>
    <ul class="gradient_menu">
    <li class="gradient_menuitem  first"><a href="Action" target="_self">Action</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Adventure" target="_self" title="">Adventure</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Animation" target="_self" title="">Animation</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Comedy" target="_self" title="">Comedy</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Crime" target="_self" title="">Crime</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Drama" target="_self" title="">Drama</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Family" target="_self" title="">Family</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Fantasy" target="_self" title="">Fantasy</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Horror" target="_self" title="">Horror</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Romance" target="_self" title="">More..</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Romance" target="_self" title="">Romance</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Sci-Fi"  target="_self" title="">Sci-Fi</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem last"><a href="Thriller" target="_self" title="">Thriller</a></li>
    </ul></li>
  <li><div class="buttonbg gradient_button"><a href="Browse" target="_self">Language</a></div>
    <ul class="gradient_menu">
    <li class="gradient_menuitem first"><a href="Arabic" target="_self" title="">Arabic</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Brazilian" target="_self" title="">Brazilian</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Dutch" target="_self" title="">Dutch</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="English" target="_self" title="">English</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="French" target="_self" title="">French</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="German" target="_self" title="">German</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Greek" target="_self" title="">Greek</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Indonesian" target="_self" title="">Indonesian</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Malay" target="_self" title="">Malay</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Norwegian" target="_self" title="">Norwegian</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Romanian" target="_self" title="">Romanian</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Spanish" target="_self" title="">Spanish</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Swedish" target="_self" title="">Swedish</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Thai" target="_self" title="">Thai</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Turkish" target="_self" title="">Turkish</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem last"><a href="Vietnamese" target="_self" title="">Vietnamese</a></li>
    </ul></li>
  <li><div class="buttonbg gradient_button"><a href="Contact/Request" target="_self">Request</a></div>
    <ul class="gradient_menu">
    <li class="gradient_menuitem first"><a href="Contact/Request-Movie" target="_self" title="">Movie</a></li>
    <li class="gradient_menuitem last"><a href="Contact/Request-Other" target="_self" title="">Other</a></li>
    </ul></li>
  <li><div class="buttonbg gradient_button"><a href="Help-us" target="_self">Help us</a></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Full http://jsfiddle.net/sfpj77p5/1/

Comment: Hey... calm down. I can't understand what you are asking. Please, reformulate your question.

Comment: Look at Language and Request go on hover and look its not working the SubMenu DropDown why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another solution is just to change the class of the other list, I changed the second one and it work

[have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/sfpj77p5/2/)

```
<ul class="gradient_menu2">
        <li class="gradient_menuitem2  first"><a href="Action" target="_self">Action</a></li>
```

Comment: Yeah I'll try to do it on all thanks..if it will work the tick its yours thanks ;p

Comment: Yeap I add 2 and 3 and add css and working for all thanks ^_^ It was so easy :D

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed because if you reverse the order of the Elements, it's always the first one that work. It must have something to do with the code, since removing it make it work.

Comment: How can I set time so when they press More.. so it will display better?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your JavaScript wasn't needed at all, I commented it out like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*$(".gradient_menuitem:gt(9)").css("display","none");

$(".gradient_menuitem:eq(9)").click ( function (e) {
                                     e.preventDefault();

             $(".gradient_menuitem:gt(9)").css("display","block");       
    $(".gradient_menuitem:eq(9)").hide();
                                     });


$(".gradient_menu").mouseleave(function(){
   $(".gradient_menuitem:gt(9)").hide();       
    $(".gradient_menuitem:eq(9)").show();
});*/
});
```

And now your menu is working just fine. [Have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/utbkmm65/).

**EDIT:** Here's what to do for the "More" button in the "Categories" menu:

```
<li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Romance" target="_self" title="">More..</a>
            <ul class="gradient_menu">
                <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Romance" target="_self" title="">Romance</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem"><a href="Sci-Fi"  target="_self" title="">Sci-Fi</a></li>
        <li class="gradient_menuitem last"><a href="Thriller" target="_self" title="">Thriller</a></li>
            </ul>
```

You simply add the "Romance", "Sci-Fi" and "Thriller" menus inside it within a `ul` tag of class "gradient_menu". [Have a look there](http://jsfiddle.net/0Ljx77p1/) and just copy the HTML. The rest is all up to your CSS.

Comment: @ComeOnHelpMe But it looks fine for me. Why do you say it's not working? Please, provide more detail.